# Why Does ClaimsPrincipal Have an AddIdentity Method But No RemoveIdentity Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, claims-based-identity

The ClaimsPrincipal class, has the ability to contain multiple ClaimsIdentitites as follows:

```
public ClaimsPrincipal(IEnumerable<ClaimsIdentity> identities)
```

ClaimsPrincipal has an add method AddIdentity to add a claims identity to this claims principal. Why is there no RemoveIdentity method?

[MSDN ClaimsPrincipal page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx%20MSDN%20ClaimsPrincipal%20page)

Answer (score 0):

Inevitably, when someone asks on SO why *some feature* doesn't exist, I always [link and quote Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx):

> I am asked "why doesn't C# implement feature X?" all the time. The answer is always the same: because no one ever designed, specified, implemented, tested, documented and shipped that feature. All six of those things are necessary to make a feature happen. All of them cost huge amounts of time, effort and money. Features are not cheap, and we try very hard to make sure that we are only shipping those features which give the best possible benefits to our users given our constrained time, effort and money budgets.

So your question is pretty useless.  However, I think what you meant to ask is:

> ClaimsPrincipal Has an AddIdentity Method, But No RemoveIdentity Method, how do I remove an Identity.

For whatever reason, the method you are looking for is not on the [ClaimsPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal), but on the [ClaimsIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsidentity) as the method [`RemoveClaim()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.removeclaim) or the preferred [`TryRemoveClaim()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.tryremoveclaim).

> Attempts to remove a claim from the claims identity.

Comment: I am aware of RemoveClaim, but that is not what I asked. RemoveClaim does not remove a ClaimsIdentity it removes a single claim from a ClaimsIdentity.

Comment: Also, I asked because it seems short-sighted to allow for multiple ClaimsIdentities and provide an Add method, but no Remove method. Perhaps they did not forsee the need to remove a ClaimsIdentity. I am genuinely interested in the rationale behind this.

Comment: It may be because when you change user, by re-authenticating, you usually change the whole principal, not just the identities. Once you know who the user is, their identity may change, but it wouldn't normally stop existing altogether.